# Adapt an existing database to WordPress format

Tags: php, android, mysql, wordpress

Given an App (Android) where the users can vote and comment my articles (using a using LAMP+json at the server). I'd like to generate the web version of the app. So I'm considering to use WordPress.

I've never used WordPress and I'd to know whats the best way of doing this job?:

- Have both database tables (app and wp) in a single database and when one change refresh the other with the new values (maybe using triggers or something like that)
- Have two separated databases each one reflecting the changes in the other (I really dont know how to do that, maybe a cron with high refresh)
- Redesign my web server for working only with an database with WordPress format and both app and web run over it
- Other sollutions?

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest making the app write to the WP database, the model isn't that hard. you would need to adjust your serverside app structure greatly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say you have two main options.

1) The most sensible would be to port your app to use the WordPress post/comment format - that would make the most sense.

2) The other option is to write a PHP or PERL script that parses the data from the application and inserts it into the WordPress app regularly. That's a bit of a hack though, it definitely makes more sense to go with 1). Because if you write the logic to do this, you may aswell just transfer it over once and for all.